# Deploy SD file to production environment

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, esri-geodatabase

I have created map service using an oracle 11g geodatabase. 
I have created the SD file which knows the exact location of my table "myPlaces". (IP of my XE, credential etc)
Now I have to send the SD file to my client so as him to publish it.
Supposing that he has created his geodatabase (in the production environment) and he has created his own user/ credentials. 
And Suppose that he has registered  his geodatabase with his server.

How Will the service undestand that the it will retrieve the data from the table "mylocations" of his geodatabase, since I cannot specify it in some way

Comment: Database connections are part of the data store configuration of each server.

Comment: Hello @Vince. This issue  is very urgent for me. I would be grateful if you could provide more information/further explanation relatively to the process of giving an SD file to the people that need to deploy the service on their own environment.

Comment: I don't have anything to add over the information provided by the documentation.

Comment: Hello @Vince. I am following the documentation as you state. However, the described process fails, since I have an issue described in here : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124433/ora-00904-physicalname-invalid-identifier-deploying-sd-file-for-different-p .Any insight on this would be welcome.

Comment: I still don't have anything to add. Tech Support would seem to be a more appropriate venue to determine if this unusual methodology is possible.